# how to make a relationship of users with reporter table

Tags: php, sql, json, laravel, relationship

I have a table named reports in which i have two columns. One is `reported_post_id` and the other is `reporter_id`. In `reporter_id` the value can be more than 1 and it's json. I want to make a relationship between the unique `reported_post_id` with the many `reporter_id` which is already saved in column as json data.

```php
public function reported() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Repoters', 'reported_post_id');
}

public function reporters() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Repoters', 'reporter_id');
}

$column = [\DB::raw("*"), \DB::raw("id as postable_id"),\DB::raw("report_type as postable_type")];

$data = Repoters::select($column)->with("repos")->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(50)->unique("reported_id");
```

I want that to show all data of `reported_post_id` with `reporter_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the [eloquent-json-relations](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations) package.

Install it:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations:"^1.1"
```

Then in your `User` model (or the relevant one):

```
class Repoters extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function reported() // or the name that you want
    {
       return $this->hasManyJson('App\Model\Repoters', 'reporter_id');
    }  //                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^the json column.

    public function reporter() // or the name that you want
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Repoters', 'reported_post_id');
    }
}
```

From the package [documentation](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations):

> ### Many-To-Many Relationships
>
> This package also introduces two new relationship types:
>   `BelongsToJson` and `HasManyJson`
>
> On Laravel 5.6.25+, you can use them to implement many-to-many
>   relationships with JSON arrays.
>
> In this example, `User` has a `BelongsToMany` relationship with
>   `Role`. There is no pivot table, but the foreign keys are stored as an
>   array in a JSON field (`users.options`):
>
> #### Array of IDs
>
> By default, the relationship stores pivot records as an array of IDs:
>
> ```
> class User extends Model
> {
>     use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;
>
>     protected $casts = [
>        'options' => 'json',
>     ];
>
>     public function roles()
>     {
>         return $this->belongsToJson('App\Role', 'options->role_ids');
>     }
> }
>
> class Role extends Model
> {
>     use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;
>
>     public function users()
>     {
>        return $this->hasManyJson('App\User', 'options->role_ids');
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: all is fine but i neet to relationship with reported_post_id with reporter_id that are in same table not diffrent one

Comment: @SajidAli is just an example if you want to relate to same model just update the related model and the keys names. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @SajidAli glad to help.